# How to use map produced by exorcist?

Tags: javascript, debugging, npm, browserify

NOTE: It might be that I am missing something obvious since I am a beginner at this.

Using **exorcist** to generate a `.map` at generation of **Browserify** bundle is easy when following the [instructions on the official webpage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exorcist).

However, how would I go about using the resulting `.map` to debug after?

Answer (score 0):

When exorcist generates a map from the Browserify bundle, it also inserts the necessary map-loading code into the bundle, so when you load the bundle, the bundle will in turn load the map on demand.

The map should be placed in the same folder as the bundle for this to work, so the relative path/URL is **./**.